# How to configure Qt - DirectX - Xinput.h

Tags: c++, qt, directx, xinput

I'm relatively new to C++ programming and Qt so this issue is probably my miss understanding of codependency. I'm trying to use the Xinput.h file within my source code, which is part of the DirectX SDK with Qt creator.
I have working source code for my solution that compiles and executes fine within Visual Studio 2008 however when I come to use it within Qt no such like as the header file is missing. I have tried to import the XInput.dll using the inbuilt libary adder

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Lib/x64/ -lXInput
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Lib/x64/ -lXInputd
else:symbian: LIBS += -lXInput
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Lib/x64/ -lXInput

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Lib/x64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Lib/x64
```

However this fails to compile giving me '_in' was not declared in this scope, does any one know how i might fix this?

The _in and _out errors come from the Xinput.h header file included in the Direct X SDK.

```
DWORD WINAPI XInputGetState
(
    __in  DWORD         dwUserIndex,  // Index of the gamer associated with the device
    __out XINPUT_STATE* pState        // Receives the current state
);
```

I thought i would include a demo for anyone unsure of what is happening:

The .Pro file from QT:

QT       += core

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = testxbox
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

   INCLUDEPATH += "...path to include file.../Include"

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/ -lXinput

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib
```

Then i just try to include the Xinput.h in my source files, and i get loads of horrendous messages. Windows VS 2008 just let's me do

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <XInput.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "XInput.lib")
```

and it works?

Comment: where does this `_in` come from? Show us the code that is at the heart of the problem.

Comment: I have placed an additional comment at the bottom of the main comment thanks Bart. I'm afraid i don't know to much more about it other than its use. I would also point out that i had checked for additional library files in may need (even added them all in) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've put xinput.lib in my project folder and added this line to a .pro file:

```
win32: LIBS += -lXInput
```

And of course added #include  in the code.

It worked.